# Finding the sum of the $x$-coordinates of all the stationary points of the curve $y^2 = x(x+1)(x-2)^4$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Consider $y^2 = x(x+1)(x-2)^4$, and find the sum of the x-coordinates of all the stationary points.

After differentiating the equation, we get $\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{(2x+1)(x-2)^4 + 4(x^2+x)(x-2)^3}{2y}$. Then letting this equal to zero, we get $x=\frac12\ or\ -\frac23\ or\ 2$.

However, the answer said that the sum is $3$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The domain should be $x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (0, \infty)$.

Comment: Your analysis was fine, but you didn't go far enough.  The three stationary points are $(2,0), \left(\frac 12, \pm \sqrt {\frac {243}{64}}\right)$.  And $2+\frac 12+\frac 12=3$.